# How to Trigger a Jenkins Job on Pull Request Close Event from Webhook

Tags: github, jenkins, devops, webhooks, cicd

We have an Enterprise Jenkins box with the [GitHub Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin) that scans orgs and creates jobs for each branch/PR etc. Repos then have a webhook which send push/pull request events to the webhook, which builds them.

I'm trying to work out how to destroy ephemeral environments *after* a Ent. GitHub PR has been closed. I figured the best way to do this would be to have the webhook invoke the job and read the GH payload on the PR close event, however it doesn't appear like this is an option from any of the GH plugin settings on the org? The webhook simply disables job on the close event rather than building.

We don't have GitHub Actions available, so that's not an avenue. How else could I invoke a build upon PR close?

Comment: What kind of Pipeline do you have? A Multibranch Pipeline?

Comment: @yrc It's a "GitHub Organisation" item from the plugin, which scans the org and populates sub-jobs as repos and their respective branches/PRs.